# Azure Compute Service degradation

Tags: sql-server, azure

I am start getting the following error today. Is this because of Azure services are down?

PDOException: SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: This extension requires either the Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Native Client (SP1 or later) or the Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Native Client ODBC Driver to communicate with SQL Server. Neither of those ODBC Drivers are currently installed. Access the following URL to download the Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Native Client ODBC driver for x86:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  That error indicates that you have a connection configuration/version issue.  The error occurs before the call out to the service.